# Need to inline the date, month and year select tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I have a Birthday field in edit user profile page as shown,

[image]

I want it to be displayed in this manner, horizontally

[image]

So far, I am using the following code,

In visitors/edit.html.erb,

```
<%= simple_form_for([@user],:url => visitor_path(@user), method: :put, :class => 'form form-horizontal') do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :birthday %>      
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= birthday_field_for(f, end_year: Date.today.year) %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In application_helper.rb,

```
def birthday_field_for(form,options={})
  date_field_for(form,:birthday,options.reverse_merge!(start_year: Date.today.year - 90, end_year: Date.today.year - 13))
end

def date_field_for(form,field,options={})
  form.date_select(field, options.reverse_merge!(order: [:day, :month, :year],
                                               include_blank: true))
end
```

Kindly help me out with css.

Comment: can u post a fiddle of the html and css u've

Comment: you're container is probably too small. simple forms date inputs are naturally inline

Comment: @Aru Please check http://jsfiddle.net/cofa5hx8/. It is coming somewhat ok here. But not in my application.

Comment: @sakshi, hope you are going to display only the select boxes (user_birthday_3i, user_birthday_2i, user_birthday_1i) as an output and the other divs (s2id_user_birthday_3i, s2id_user_birthday_2i, s2id_user_birthday_1i) are for your manupulation!! if yes, then you can write a css like... (.col-sm-2 div{display:none;}) will fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answer people!

The width of select containers wad set to 100%. Because of which the next select tab was appearing in the new line.

Adding a css in visitors/edit.html.erb, did solve my problem,

```
<% content_for :head_css do %>
  <style type="text/css">
    .select2-container {
      width: 120px !important;
    }
  </style>
<% end %>
```